# How to remove time from datetime column in excel sheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, c#-4.0

I have written lines of code as

```
public static void GenrateExcel(DataSet ds, string FileName, string TemplateName)
{
 try
    {
       ReplcateColumnSpace(ds);

       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

       XmlDataDocument xdd = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
       XslTransform xt = new XslTransform();
       xt.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelTemplate/" + TemplateName + ".xsl"));
       xt.Transform(xdd, null, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ".xls");
       //   HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It generates excel sheet from ds (dataset).There is a column in dataset Expiry Date. Now whenever this function is called and excel sheet is generated successfully. Time also gets appended to the column Expiry Date in excel sheet document. I want to remove time from the expiry date column and date should come in mm/dd/yyyy format. Please help !!!

Comment: Have you tried changing the DateTimeFormat of the culture info?

Comment: i do not have any idea about excel sheet generated from code in c#... Please help!!!

Comment: Excel is simply using your CultureInfo settings. You have dates in your DataSet and what excel does is simply converting them to strings. The way the dates will be printed depends on the format for the particular culture.

Comment: Can you please provide code for better understanding as i dont have any idea about it

Comment: Open your DB and see the format of the dates there. Is it the same as in your excel file?

Comment: No it is not. I am surprised that query result from db contains date only.  then in dataset time gets itself appended to column and in excel sheet... Please  help me !!!

Comment: Try creating a new CultureInfo and set its DateTimeFormat and then change the CurrentCulture of your application with the new custom culture.

Comment: i don't know how to create culture info... please help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to change the dataset:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            if (dt.Columns.Contains("ExpiryDate"))
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    dr["ExpiryDate"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["ExpiryDate"].ToString())).Date;
                }
            }
        }
```